# SP2010 - Search results return exact same file more than once

Tags: 2010, fast-search

I have two WFEs in my environment running SP2010 and FAST Search Server 2010 on a Fast Content Service SSA. There are 9 site collections that are covered in the Content Source of that SSA. I have a file called "uniqueFile.txt" and it's part of the Site Assets of each site collection.

When I run a search for "uniqueFile.txt" it shows 17 results with 16 duplicates. Half of these duplicates are because this same file exists at different locations, however the other half of the results return are pointing to the exact same file twice (Same URL, same doc id.. etc).

I have gone through the crawl logs and these files have been crawled multiple times and each time it has the same Crawl ID.

What troubleshooting steps can you recommend?

Comment: Sounds like the search index and crawl log is not in sync. Have you ever done index resets without clearing the FAST collection?

Comment: No I haven't done that - is this what you're talking about [Reset the content index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191228(v=office.14).aspx)?

Comment: Mikael - I tried as you suggested in my DEV environment to see if I could replicate the problem but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Mikael - I did it about 10-15 times in my DEV environment to see if I could break it and it looks like i've been able to replicate the issue. Thanks heaps mate, this issue has been haunting our production environment for a while now.

Comment: how did you reproduce it?

Comment: I did an index reset and then a full crawl without clearing the FAST collection about 10-15 times which eventually reproduced the problem. Then I did an index reset, cleared the FAST collection, and then full crawl which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall fix was to turn off Case Sensitive Crawling:

SharePoint Powershell:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "FAST Content Service App"
$ssa.GetProperty("CaseSensitiveCrawling")
```

This should return **False**.

```
$ssa.SetProperty("CaseSensitiveCrawling",0)
$ssa.Update()
$ssa.GetProperty("CaseSensitiveCrawling")
```

This should return **True**.

Perform an index reset, following the instructions for clearing on the FAST Server also.

Answer (score 1):

When you do an index reset with FAST in central admin you also have to clear the content collection using powershell from one of the FAST servers. This ensures the crawl database and index are in sync.

Comment: It looks like after a few weeks the problem has reoccured, this time I know there hasn't been any index resets or clearing of the FAST collection.

Comment: What kind of crawl schedules have you set up, and weird indeed.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary - it does an incremental every 30 mins and a full crawl every week.